# subtracting time values from columns

Tags: powerbi

Sup, simple question ( i hope). I am adding a custom column in Power bi. I need to subtract time values, using custom column formula. Problem: (B-A)-C causes error.

Values are set to time type.

```
B = 15.00.00
A = 9.00.00
C = 0.05.00
```

custom column formula:

```
=([B]-[A])-[C]
```

Result i want: 5.55.55 
Result i get:

```
Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator - to types Duration and Time.
Details:
    Operator=-
    Left=0.06:00:00
    Right=0.05.00
```

So B-A = 0.06:00:00 and therefore 0.06:00:00 - 0.05.00 = error. I need to get B-A result in shape of 06.00.00 so i can subtract value C from it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your table is called "Table":

First, create a new column and calculate the difference of B and A.

`Col1 = DATEDIFF(Table1[B],Table1[A],HOUR)`

Then create another column and subtract C from it.

`Col2 = DATEDIFF(Table1[Col1],Table1[C],HOUR)`